# How to get an error message as string in CPython

Tags: python, c++, embed, cpython

When I call `PyRun_SimpleString(...)` in C++ and my Python script contains invalid syntax or an error, I get an error message that gets printed to my console.

How can I stop that error message from getting flushed to the console and instead, get that error message as a *string* or a `const char*` and probably use that string in my own way (display it as a GUI text or something)?

Answer (score 6):

`PyRun_SimpleString` is a simplified interface to `PyRun_SimpleStringFlags`, and quoting the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.PyRun_SimpleStringFlags) for `PyRun_SimpleStringFlags`:

> If there was an error, there is no way to get the exception information.

Also pretty important,

> Note that if an otherwise unhandled SystemExit is raised, this function will not return -1, but exit the process, as long as Py_InspectFlag is not set.

You probably don't want that.

---

You should instead be using [`PyRun_String`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.PyRun_String) or [`PyRun_StringFlags`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.PyRun_StringFlags). Probably `PyRun_StringFlags`, since it lets you remember the effects of `__future__` imports.

`PyRun_StringFlags` has the following signature:

> `PyObject* PyRun_StringFlags(const char *str, int start, PyObject *globals, PyObject *locals, PyCompilerFlags *flags)`

- `str` is the source string to run.
- `start` is either `Py_eval_input`, `Py_file_input`, or `Py_single_input`, depending on whether you want this to behave like `eval`, like running a script, or like running a statement interactively. `Py_eval_input` only allows a single expression, the value of which will be returned from the `PyRun_StringFlags` call. `Py_single_input` does stuff like expression auto-printing, and only allows one (possibly-compound) statement. You probably want `Py_file_input` or `Py_single_input` (and if you use `Py_single_input`, you might want a custom [`sys.displayhook`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook)).
- `globals` and `locals` are the global and local dicts to use, just like when calling `exec` or `eval`. You probably want to fetch the `__main__` module's `__dict__`, like this:

  ```
  m = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
  if (m == NULL)
      /* bad stuff happened */
      do_something_about_that();
  Py_INCREF(m);
  d = PyModule_GetDict(m);
  ...
  /* later, when you're done with m and d */
  Py_DECREF(m);
  ```

  and use `d` for both of these arguments.

  `PyImport_AddModule` and `PyModule_GetDict` both return borrowed references, but I've used `Py_INCREF` to get a new reference for `m`, and `Py_DECREF` when we're done with that reference. That's because the reference `PyImport_AddModule` returns is borrowed from `sys.modules['__main__']`, and it's possible that something could *remove* `__main__` from `sys.modules`. (There's no such worry with `d`, because that's borrowed from `__main__.__dict__`, which cannot be deleted or reassigned as long as `__main__` itself survives. As long as our `m` reference is safe, `d` is safe.)
- `flags` is a pointer to a struct with one relevant field, an `int` representing compiler flags. `__future__` imports affect this field. To make sure `__future__` statements from one `PyRun_StringFlags` call are still active in the next call, you should create a struct somewhere it won't be deallocated or wiped between runs:

  ```
  PyCompilerFlags flags = {0};
  ```

  and pass `&flags` as this argument. If you *don't* want to remember `__future__` statement effects, you can pass `NULL`, or use `PyRun_String`, which doesn't have this argument.

---

`PyRun_StringFlags` will return a Python object on success (usually `None`, and remember to decref the reference) and NULL on an exception. If there's an exception, you can inspect it through the [C-level API for exception handling](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html#querying-the-error-indicator), particularly [`PyErr_Fetch`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html#c.PyErr_Fetch), [`PyErr_NormalizeException`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html#c.PyErr_NormalizeException), and [`PyException_SetTraceback`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html#c.PyException_SetTraceback).

Running the following while an exception is set:

```
PyObject *type, *val, *tb;
PyErr_Fetch(&type, &val, &tb);
```

is sort of the C-level equivalent to entering an `except` block and fetching `sys.exc_info()`, except that `val` might be `NULL` or not an instance of `type`, and the exception's `__traceback__` attribute might not be set. The following:

```
PyErr_NormalizeException(&type, &val, &tb);
if (tb != NULL) {
  PyException_SetTraceback(val, tb);
}
```

does that normalization, if you need it.